# MediaCodecBufferedOutput index is negative for android MediaCodec

Tags: java, android, signal-processing, android-mediacodec, video-encoding

Following is a code snippet which is supposed to read all images from image folder and encode them to a h.262 video and store in the sdcard. I followed the android documentation (get buffer, fill buffer, queue buffer for encoding, dequeue output buffer and then write to file). Problem is when I dequeue output buffer I get negative index whereas its supposed to return the index of output data. The output file is 0 Bytes and nothing is written into it.
I am pretty much very new in mediaCodec. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
MediaCodec mediaCodec=null;
    byte[] input = new byte[2000];
    BufferedOutputStream outputStream = null;

    try {
        //TODO
        //adjust parameters by consulting with hari sir

        mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");
        MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 320, 240);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 700000);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 10);

        //not all phones support given color format, if color format is not supported app will crash with mediaCodec exception
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);

        mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);


        mediaCodec.start();
        //after the mediaCodec is started we don't have ownership of input or output buffers

        Log.i("Codecinfo",""+mediaCodec.getCodecInfo());
        Log.i("Codecname",""+mediaCodec.getName());


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("ExceptionMediaCodec","Some exception in media codec");
    }

    //reached here
    System.out.println("mediacodec info="+mediaCodec.getCodecInfo());


    try {
        File ff = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Download/video_encoded.264");
        if (!ff.exists()) ff.createNewFile();
        System.out.println("H.264 output file initialized");

        outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(ff));
        Log.i("H264 avc Encoder", "outputStream initialized");
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/images";
    File f = new File(path);
    Log.i("ExternalFileInfo",path.toString());
    //read image files onto an array
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    System.out.println(files.getClass().getName());
    int NUM_IMAGES = files.length;
    String[] images = new String[NUM_IMAGES];
    for (int i=0;i<NUM_IMAGES;i++)
            images[i]=files[i].getName();



    for (String eachimage: images) {
        System.out.println(eachimage);
        byte[] eachByte = eachimage.getBytes();
        input = eachByte; //demo
        System.out.println("input byte initialized"+input.toString());
        try {
            System.out.println("Following is the content of byte array input");
            System.out.write(input);
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    //reached here
    System.out.println("image byte size="+input.length);
    //all images converted to bytearray


    ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();

    //System.out.println("inputBuffers="+(inputBuffers));
    //System.out.println("outputBuffers="+(outputBuffers));
    //reached here

    //returns the index of input buffer to be filled for encoding
    int inputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(-1); //-1 => wait indefinitely

    System.out.println("inputBufferedIndex="+inputBufferIndex); //0

    if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
        ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = mediaCodec.getInputBuffers();

        ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];


        inputBuffer.clear();

        System.out.println("input byte placed in input buffer");
        inputBuffer.put(input);



        System.out.println("inputBuffer after filling up" + inputBuffer);


        mediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, input.length, System.nanoTime(), 0); //send each request with different timestamp


        System.out.println("mediacodec input  queued");

        }

    MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    System.out.println("buffer info="+bufferInfo);

    int outputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, -1); //-ve value for indefinite waiting

    //reached here
    System.out.println("buffer info meta data=" + bufferInfo);


    System.out.println("outputBufferedIndex=" + outputBufferIndex);

        try {
            while (outputBufferIndex >= 0) {
                ByteBuffer outputBuffer = outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];
                byte[] outData = new byte[bufferInfo.size];
                outputBuffer.get(outData);
                outputStream.write(outData, 0, outData.length);
                outputStream.flush();
                Log.i("AvcEncoder", outData.length + " bytes written");

                mediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
                outputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, -1);

            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }


    try {
        mediaCodec.stop();
        mediaCodec.release();

        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Mediacodec="+mediaCodec);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the documentation for the `MediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer()` method, which says:

> Returns the index of an output buffer that has been successfully decoded or one of the INFO_* constants.

The negative values are the INFO_* constants, which may be one of the following:

- `INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED`
- `INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED`
- `INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER`

The last one is not too probable because you're waiting indefinitely though.

Additionally: You can't always rely on waiting for one output buffer after you've given one single buffer as input. You need to feed input buffers as long as the encoder has got free input buffers, and consume whatever output buffers it gives you.

The last few output buffers might be output only once you signal that you won't be submitting any more input buffers, by setting the flag `BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM`.

Comment: I found that INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED is what's happening in my case. What should be my next step?

Comment: After that you should call `dequeueOutputBuffer()` again.